# Maven Assembly - copy result to svn

Tags: svn, maven, target, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm creating a ZIP using an assembly plugin. I would like to commit this brand new file to my svn. Do you have any idea of the best way to do it?

I tried some different solutions without success.

Comment: BTW, storing build artifacts in repo is, in common, **bad idea**

Comment: I just need a maven plugin to commit one file to a svn. Do you know one ?

Comment: Let me join the chorus w/ @Lazy Badger.  Do not commit build artifacts to a source control repository.  It's called "source" for a reason.

Comment: Create the zip archive during your build and deploy it into the repository (Repository manager).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Use the [Maven SCM Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html).  You can configure specific `<executions>` of the plugin attached to your package phase (and more likely to a `<profile>`) that run the [`scm:add` goal](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/add-mojo.html) and then the [`scm:checkin` goal](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html).